# Ubnutu/MySQL - Error "Unable to locate package innotop"

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, with MySQL 5.5.29.

Im trying to install innotop for database monitoring, but getting an error "Unable to locate package innotop"

```
root@server1:~# apt-get install innotop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package innotop
```

I checked the Ubuntu package site at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=innotop&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all
and there is no mention, but I know I used to see it there.

```
root@server1:~# apt-get update
```

did not help.

I think I might have once had this problem before, and fixed it by installing some prerequisite, but I cant recall anymore.

I checked Google for the error message, but no mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be in the [file list for **mysql-client-5.5**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/mysql-client-5.5/filelist).

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5` should be all you need to do.

Note that the `mysql` client program is in a separate package, `mysql-client-core-5.5`, so it's possible to have `mysql` installed without any of the other useful tools like `mysqladmin` or `mysqldump`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it.  If I can hire you for paid MySQL work please let me know how I can contact you.